# мне нужно создать массив с размером n(n-1) правильно ли я его создал?

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

```
import numpy as np
a = np.empty((n,(n - 1)))
```

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html

Comment: Что значит "размером n(n-1)"?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, неправильно. Хотя бы потому, что у вас в приведенном коде не задано значение переменной `n`.

Но вот если вы эту переменную зададите, то потом сможете и самостоятельно получить ответ на свой суперсложный вопрос, например -  выведя в консоль свой массив `а`.

А вообще -  очень странная практика: написать код и спрашивать, правильный-ли он, вместо того, что-бы взять да запустить его и посмотреть на результат. Допускаю это в единственном случае -  у вас отобрали компьютер и вы пишете программу на листочке. Я угадал?

Answer (score 0):

Если посмотреть [документацию](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html), то первый параметр там действительно размер создаваемого массива в виде кортежа. Но как уже вам ответили, поскольку `n` не определено, этот код просто не отработает. И метод `empty` создаёт массив, заполненный неизвестно какими произвольными значениями. Вам это точно нужно? Обычно используют, например, `zeros`, чтобы получить первоначально массив, заполненный нулями.